# How can I understand "absurdly gross"

Tags: phrases

I have read a tweet: "`the way Apple’s DTrace port controls processes is absurdly gross ....`". How can I understand "`absurdly gross`" in this sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would interpret that to mean the author finds the way Apple's DTrace port controls processes is ugly (hackish, kludgy, slap-dash, slipshod, careless, etc)

*absurdly* in the sense of comical or laughable

*gross* meaning disgusting or horrible

I would also note that DTrace originated on [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-6223/) so it isn't very surprising that porintg it to Mac OS X wasn't trivial (or *clean*).